# ¿A qué hace referencia la palabra delante de mi variable?

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A lo que me refiero es si el `Car` en el recuadro amarillo, ¿está haciendo referencia a la clase Car o al constructor Car?

Comment: Por favor, al agregar código, pegalo como texto. Si hay que marcar una parte específica, se pueden utilizar comentarios.

Answer (score 3):

`Car` es el tipo de dato que va a tener la variable `myFastCar`, en este caso, hace referencia a un objeto `Car`.

Por el contrario, cuando haces `new Car(2007)` estás utilizando el constructor de dicho objeto para inicializar el objeto `myFastCar`.

Answer (score 0):

La que está en el recuadro amarillo hace referencia a la clase, es decir, estás declarando una variable de tipo `Car`. La parte de código `new Car(2007)` está haciendo referencia al constructor `public Car(int year)` con lo cual estás instanciando la clase que está recibiendo un parámetro de tipo `int`

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo tengo claro :)

Comment: *La que está en el recuadro amarillo hace referencia a la clase, es decir, estás creando una instancia de la clase Car* **totalmente equivocado**. @saeta cuidado. Esa parte del código `Car myFastCar` es **declaración de la variable**, no tiene **absolutamente nada que ver** con crear una instancia. La parte `new Car(2007)` **sí se asocia con crear la instancia**. No puedo creer que una respuesta tan mala tenga 2 votos a favor.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza gracias por tu comentario, ya he editado la respuesta que evidentemente estaba mal. A veces por ayudar de manera rápida a la comunidad no nos damos cuenta exactamente qué es lo que estamos escribiendo y ese fue el caso en mi respuesta, una disculpa y muy acertada tu observación

Comment: La respuesta sigue mal...

Comment: ¿En qué sigue estando mal?

Comment: *estás declarando una clase de tipo `Car`* falso, estás declarando una variable de tipo `Car`. Imagina si tuvieses una clase padre `Vehicle` y `Car` extiende de `Vehicle`, entonces podrías colocar algo como `Vehicle car = new Car(2007);`

Comment: De acuerdo con tu comentario, ya quedó corregida, aunque un poco de ayuda editando la respuesta desde un inicio hubiera estado mejor!

Answer (score 0):

Declaración de tipos de datos, sirve para indicar que es tu variable y así poder reservar un espacio de memoria acorde a esta.

Te dejo algunos ejemplos:

```
int i = 1; //ocupa 4 bytes
int j; //ocupa 4 bytes aunque no le hayas indicado el nº entero,
//pero ya ha reservado un espacio de memoria para tu variable j.

byte k = 2;//Ocupa un 1 byte y puede ser cualquier entero de -127 a
//128. ¿El motivo? Un byte (por lo general) tiene 8 bit, eso significa
//que podemos obtener un intervalo de 255 números enteros (2 elevado a 8 - 1)
// y con el fin de abarcar tanto enteros positivos como negativos, se distribuyen
//desde el -127 a 128 (127+128 = 255 = 8 bit = byte).
```

A los anteriores tipos de datos y otros que **no necesitan ser invocados**, se les conoce como **tipos de datos primitivos**, por el contrario los **objetos** (clases) se denominan **tipos objeto**.

En los lenguajes más robustos es necesaria la declaración de tipos de variable, sin embargo otros como PHP o JavaScript no; el propio lenguaje se encarga de declarar el tipo y espacio de memoria que asignará a una variable, esto presenta inconvenientes y así PHP por ejemplo te permite definir el tipo de dato:

```
$i = 1;//Establece el tipo de la variable como int (1)
$i = (boolean) 1;//Establece el tipo de la variable como booleana (true)
```

Esto ha sido todo por mi parte, espero haber aclarado tus ideas.
¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Hace referencia al tipo del dato.  Cuando se hace referencia al constructor es cuando pones New Car() ;

Comment: ¿En qué se diferencia de las respuestas ya publicadas?